# Integrating JavaScript with Java Backend

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

Trying to find the best way to make a quasi java-javascript web application. I want to write a java servlet (for the controller and backend) with a jQuery front end. What's the best approach to having these two communicate with each other? I'm used to coding in both but never worked on them together.

Can anybody help me out? I suppose a start would be having a Java Servlet call from jQuery code and getting a response back from the servlet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery's **ajax function**. Here is a simple example:

```
// Servlet
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AjaxHandler extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().print("Hello jQuery!");
    }
}

// View.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : '/AjaxHandler', // servlet mapping ("web.xml")
                success : function(responseText) {
                    $('#ajaxHandlerResponse').text(responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    Servlet's message: <span id="ajaxHandlerResponse"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create REST backend using one of JAX-RS implementations ([Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/), [RESTeasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) etc.). Writing web service with plain old Servlet API is tedious.

You can start learning JAX-RS from [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html).